# Can I access other Google User's Calendars through the Google API v3

Tags: php, zend-framework2, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-client

I would like to build an application that manages appointments in Google calendar on behalf of my users when they are not logged in.

The application would be a booking service, subscribing users (our service providers) would book out the times they are not available, and customers would see a free/busy representation of the service provider's google calendar

The application would need the ability to create, delete, and read appointments.

I have gone to the Google Developer's Console and have working code that pops up the Google Permissions screen, then redirects to a Url that successfully creates a new appointment.

I can access other calendar's but only if they are are logged into Google services at that time.

```
$client = new \Google_Client(); 
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

This works okay if the user is managing their own Calendar.  However, I want to manage appointments on their behalf.  This would include others parties entering appointments into the calendar - i.e. when the calendar is not logged in.

What I need is an enduring authority for application to gain enduring access to my user's calendar?

Does anyone know if this possible? Thoughts as to how I could approach the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 service accounts are the proper method for accessing user accounts:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

You need to grant the service account client id access to the necessary Calendar API scopes:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Then your service account can impersonate your users and perform calendar operations on their behalf:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object

These docs describe Google Drive but the process for Calendar is identical.

Comment: The documentation describes a "within your domain" is this the same as the domain that a business may have?  If an unknown third party comes through the App and authenticates themselves and grants permission would this work - or would I need to issue them a calendar in my domain, which it appears could be limited to 600 users.

Comment: I'm curious as well, I want my users to add an email related to their preferred calendar trough the application. The application will hold the main calendar that shows activity for each joined calendar. BY example, each user is a field rep with appointments, by connecting to their calendar, the application displays all events. I understand this can manage all user by domain, but most have their own cals. They could share their calendar with a domain related calendar, but then I have issue new accounts to every rep. Could you explain the relationship to outside calendars for other gmail

Comment: I have the same question. Say I have two and more domains for different businesses.
Business A:
 - Employee_a1
 - Employee_a2

Business B:
 - Employee_b1

All employees have Google email accounts. I am able to two-way synchronize the calendars for each employee.

But, what if Employee_a1 uses Employee_b1 email account. 

Employee_a1 will get Employee_b1 events? So I am not sure how the domain is going to work in this case?